# Turning multi-line string into array in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, type-conversion

I am making a function that can turn a number into a simplified radical square root. I have so far made a function that can return the factors of a number. I want to turn the string into an array so I can index through the numbers in a for loop and test if they have a perfect square root. How can I do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
  public static void factor(int num) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i) {
      if (num % i == 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
      }
    }
  }
```

inputing the number 20 outputs

```
1
2
4
5
10
20
```

I want to turn this into {1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20}

Comment: Use an ArrayList and push the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store them in a List when you print.

```
public static void factor(int num) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i) {
      if (num % i == 0) {
        list.add(i);
        System.out.println(i);
      }
    }

    //iterate over the list
    for(int val: list){
       //do something with val
     }

  }
```

However if you only want to convert a multi-line string to an array, do

```
yourMultiLineString.split("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a list of integers and push your data into it just like the `list` in below code:

```
public static void factor(int num) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i) {
      if (num % i == 0) {
         list.add(i);
      }
    }
    for(Integer i: list) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    // OR via indexing
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read using a `Scanner`, store in a `List`, then use the `.toArray()` method.

```
List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    l.add(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));
}
int[] arr = (int[]) l.toArray();
```